# AEM multifield data-sly-repeat ${item} not working

Tags: aem, repeat, sightly, htl

This has been driving me nuts - hoping someone can help me.

I have a multifield component called 'books' with a single textfield: 'title'.

Everything seems to be working; the dialog box contains the multifield then I add two title fields then enter 'title1' and 'title2'.

then in the HTML itself I go:

```
<div data-sly-repeat="${properties.books}">
  <p>${item}</p>
  <p>${itemList.index</p>
  <p>${item.title}</p>
</div>
```

What I don't get is, ${item} correctly gives me:
{"title": "title1"} {"title": "title2"}

and ${itemList.index} correctly gives me: 0 1

but ${item.title} keeps coming up blank. I also tried ${item["title"]} and that comes up blank too.

What am I doing wrong here? In my desperation I contemplated using

```
<div data-title="${item}"></div>
```

and then using JS to process the JSON object but I don't really want to do that.

Someone help, please!

Comment: item has to be a Java object, seems you have a JSON string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your `books` property is either a `JSON` array string or a multivalued property with each value being a `JSON` object string;

The easiest way to parse the property is via a JS model like the following:

> You could simplify this script to match your specific case, I made it general to multi-value and non-multi-value string properties.

**/path/to/your-component/model.js**:

```
"use strict";
use(function () {

    // parse a JSON string property, including multivalued, returned as array
    function parseJson(prop){
        if(!prop) return [];
        var result =[];
        if(prop.constructor === Array){
            prop.forEach(function(item){
                result.push(JSON.parse(item));
            });
        }
        else {
            var parsed = JSON.parse(prop);
            if(parsed.constructor === Array){
                result = parsed;
            }
            else result = [parsed];
        }
        return result;

    }

    var $books = properties.get("books", java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(java.lang.String, 1));
    var books = parseJson($books);

    return {
        books: books
    }

});
```

**/path/to/your-component/your-component.html**:

```
<sly data-sly-use.model="model.js"/>
<div data-sly-repeat="${model.books}">
  <p>${item}</p>
  <p>${itemList.index</p>
  <p>${item.title}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Of course I am missing the JS bit - I initially thought that I can just process the object with Sightly directly in the HTML. Thank you - I will give this a go.

Comment: It’s a string, HTL (sightly) wont parse JSON for you, you have to do it in a model

Comment: Yes I get it now. Thanks - I will try this today.